# UAV spy drone Location Problem. locationg a 3d vector from another

Tags: python, math, geometry, dronekit-python

So I randomly got bored and am now trying to figure out how to make the call of duty spy plane using a drone. I figured its basic geometry and I posted my math below. I am looking for help to make this more accurate as my project is open source and agricultural based.

Problem instance:
-
An Rc airplane equiped with a GIMBAL camera is at V1 or vector one.
with g1 or gimbal angle and A1 be azimuth/direction (N,S,E,W).
A person in the field is v2 or vector 2. Assume the gimbal angle directly points at the person or v2.
if given V1(x,y,z),r, A1, G1, please find the location of the person or v2(x1,y1,z1).
V1=(39.375346,10, -84.208137)
G1=45 degrees
A1= 3.14/4 or 45 degrees
R= 10 radius to target or distance to target
180 degrees = west
90 degrees = south
270 degrees = north0
0 degrees = east

```
#python example.

    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


    #code by adam dabdoub


    import math 
    import numpy

    x = 39.375346
    y = 10.0
    z = -84.208137
    V1 = {'X': x, 'Y': y, 'Z': z}
    G1 = math.degrees(45) #degrees
    A1 = math.degrees(45) # or 45 degrees
    R = 10 #radius to target or distance to target

    #180 degrees = west
    #90 degrees = south
    #270 degrees = north
    #0 degrees = east

    a = y
    c = a//(math.cos(a))
    b = math.sqrt(c ** 2 + a ** 2)
    x1 = (b * math.cos(A1) + x)
    y1 = ((y - y) + 4)
    z1 = (b * math.sin(A1) + z) 
    V2 = (x1,y1,z1)
    print("UAV Cordinates:\n", V1)
    print("Person Cordinates:\n", V2)
```

Comment: What is your question? You didn't ask a question.

Comment: Are you or are you not given the distance from the camera to the person?

Comment: You are not given the distance. the only know variables are the gimble angle, the direction the drone is facing relative to north(assumed facing directly at object), the height of the drone, the drones lat /long.

Comment: basically i want to be able to put in real world coordinates and return real world coordinates.